# Problem with direction convention with angular velocity and angular displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

Example 16.17, on page 380 of the dynamics part of the 14th edition of R.C. Hibbeler's Engineering Mechanics: Statics & Dynamics, states:

The crankshaft $AB$ turns with a clockwise angular acceleration of $20\;\text{rad/s}^2$. Determine the acceleration of the piston at the instant $AB$ is in the position shown. At this instant $\omega_{AB} = 10\;\text{rad/s}$ and $\omega_{BC} = 2.43\;\text{rad/s}$.

[image]

The book gives the answer $a_C = -13.5\;\text{ft/s}^2$ using the relative acceleration equation method.

If I do it like this:

Let $AC = x, \angle BAC = \theta$,
$$x = \sqrt{0.25^2+0.75^2+2\times0.25\times0.75\times \cos(\theta + \sin^{-1}(\sin(\theta)/3))}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac {dx}{dt} = \frac {dx}{d\theta} \frac {d\theta}{dt}$$
$$\frac {d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac {d^2x}{d\theta^2}\left(\frac {d\theta}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac {dx}{d\theta} \frac {d^2\theta}{dt^2} = \frac {d^2x}{d\theta^2}\omega^2 + \frac {dx}{d\theta} \alpha$$

Then $a_C = \frac {d^2x}{dt^2}$ evaluated at $\theta=\frac {\pi}{4},\;\omega=10\;\text{rad/s},\;\alpha=20\;\text{rad/s}^2$ which gives $a_C = -22.3\;\text{ft/s}^2$.

What should be the signs of $\omega$ and $\alpha$ be and why, given the convention implicitly specified in Eq (1) on $\theta$?

Comment: I finally figured it out. Did it, and got the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After some closer inspection, I finally noticed the mistake! There is an inconsistency with direction. ***Assume counter clockwise is positive.*** When your $\theta$ INCREASES in magnitude, then your rod ${AB}$ is moving COUNTER CLOCKWISE, so $\omega$ is POSITIVE.

Now if your rod is to move ***clockwise***, then $\omega$ must be NEGATIVE! Same thing with $\alpha$ -- 'stick' a negative in front of it too.

Negate $\alpha$ and you shall arrive at the correct answer. Cheers.

---

If you choose clockwise to be positive, it gets a bit more complicated, because of the way your equation is set up.

Comment: Thanks. You are bang on correct.